# Preserve newline within interpolated block in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a variable I'm passing into a haml template called `note` which contains newline breaks:

```
"Hi Charlie\nHope you're doing well\nLove,\nKim"
```

When I render that block in the template:

```
%i
  #{note}
```

It comes out with all of it's newlines stripped. Is there a way to force the render of newline?

I also attempted ...

```
%i
  ~ "#{note}"
```

To no avail.

Comment: `<br>` is a line break in html, not `\n`, haml is rendered into html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper for this.  It will turn single `\n` characters into `<br />` or double `\n\n` into `<p>` tags:

```ruby
= simple_format note, nil, wrapper_tag: 'i'
```

You'll end up with HTML like the following:

```html
<i>Hi Charlie<br />Hope you're doing well<br />Love,<br />Kim</i>
```